# Missing SSD partition after reboot - shows unformatted

Tags: macos, partitioning, ssd

**EDITED** to clarify commenter's question.
This just happened to 2 different Mac Mini systems that I managed.

After reboot, got the flashing folder (no startup disk found). Opt-boot showed nothing. Opened it up and re-seated sata connector, still nothing. Booted to external installer, and disk utility sees the SSD but shows it as unformatted and unpartitioned. `diskutil list` shows the same. The data is still there; running `cat rdisk0` starts spitting out raw data.

It's strange that this happened almost simultaneously on 2 different systems. On the first one, it happened spontaneously. On the second, it happened after I installed new RAM (replaced the original after the problem, but didn't have any effect).

Any ideas on how to recover the partition, or the data from it? It's not a huge loss if I can't, but I don't maintain a base image, so I'd have to set them up from scratch.

Comment: What is the flashing folder? What OS?

Comment: Updated answer to reflect. macOS. Flashing folder indicates that the startup disk is not found.

Comment: Cool. Glad you found a solution and that you shared it here. Well done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for both systems. I created a Knoppix live DVD to use as a bootable rescue OS. Knoppix ships with `testdisk`, which allows you to examine and modify the partition table.

When I ran testdisk, it showed the EFI partition and and HFS partition. I was concerned at first because testdisk wasn't able to show any files on the partition (a feature that usually works), but having no other apparent options, I had testdisk write the changes it proposed to the partition table. After that, I rebooted and the startup disk was found without issue. Repeated this action on the other system with the same results.

I still don't know exactly what caused this problem, but this definitely solved it.